# Is There a Visual Studio 2005 ASP.NET debug and release build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, build, debugging, release

Is there a "debug" and "release" build in VS 2005? If so, how do I switch between the two?

Comment: I'm sure there must be some reason why you don't already know the answer to this. Perhaps you are not near your computer right now, or perhaps you do not have VS2005 installed. Please say which, because otherwise, one may be left to wonder.

Comment: Mr. Saunders - fyi I am running VS2008, just installed VS2005 to test something on another machine and can't seem to find the feature in the IDE to switch between biuld...please stop wordering...I thought we are suppose to help each other out ont his site.

Comment: Knowing the reason you wanted to know makes it easier to be of more help to you. In fact, I recommend that you edit your question to include what you just now said. In fact, you should add that you were talking about an ASP.NET Web Site, which is different from everything else.

Comment: very well Mr. Saunders. Point taken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saif:

Are you working on an ASP.NET web site project?

If so, Visual Studio delegates the build step to the ASP.NET runtime, and the ASP.NET runtime picks up debug versus release in the web.config .

I have a post on the topic that will help: [Debug and Release Builds in ASP.NET 2.0](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/11/15/2464.aspx)

Note that a couple things have changed since that time. Namely, MSFT released two add-ins for VS 2005 - one to add [real web application projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336618.aspx) that have debug and release settings (for the code-behind and loose c# files), and they also released [web deployment projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336619.aspx), which can use the asp.net command line compiler. Web App projects became a part of VS2005 in SP1, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Configuration Manager.  Right-click on your solution in the Solution Explorer, select "Configuration Manager...", and change the active solution configuration.

You can change your project's behavior when in debug or release mode.  Bring up your project properties pane, select the appropriate configuration from the dropdowns at top, and change the settings as appropriate.  Notice that some changes are made by default for you.  For instance, release builds by default are set to optimize code, and debug builds are not.

Comment: dude, all I see is "Active(Debug)".

Comment: Then perhaps there is only a Debug build in the solution?

Comment: Wyatt's right on.  You can create a new config in the configuration manager.

Answer (score 1):

In the ASP.NET web.config file there is a debug="true" attribute. The first time you run the web application Visual Studio will ask you if you want to turn on debugging, selecting yes will cause Visual Studio to edit the config file for you.

Just remember to make sure you change that back to false for your release builds. For more info click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The quick way is to right click on the toolbars and turn on the standard toobar.  Then you can quickly change between build targets by choosing the one you want from the solutions configuration drop down.

If you want to change what those configurations do, then follow what Michael Petrotta said in his answer.